# Database Syntax Error when attempting upgrade

Tags: drupal, upgrade, error, database, trigger

I  have a website that is on Drupal 7 and I am attempting to upgrade the version of Civi from 5.10 to 5.13 but when I attempt to upgrade it, I'm receiving the following error:

```
Database Error Code: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-b_before_insert' at line 1, 1064
```

I have tried doing the upgrade through drush and also through the /civicrm/upgrade URL with the same error.

It's a bit of a long shot but I was hoping that someone has seen the error before and knows of a fix or how I can determine exactly what is going on.

Taking a look at the debugging information, I can see it has something to do with triggers:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS civicrm_saved_search-b_before_insert [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-b_before_insert' at line 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I realised what was happening. For some reason, there was a second `civicrm_saved_search` table in the database named `civicrm_saved_search-b` .

That hyphen `-` is an 'illegal' character unless you escape it.

To resolve the issue, all I did was change the `-` to a `_` which cleared everything up and enabled me to upgrade my site within minutes.

Hopefully, this will help someone else one day who has a similar issue!

Comment: That does bring up an interesting point though - maybe this function should escape the trigger names? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.14/CRM/Logging/Schema.php#L250

Comment: I was thinking that myself,  decided against changing the core files. I'm not sure whether this would be an issue or just an isolated incident...